# Can I write "...argue it sufficiently..."?

Tags: grammar, expressions, american-english

in a scientific paper written in American English, I am using the following sentence:
"...we would argue that it is sufficiently established that..."

Can the sentence be shortened to "...we would argue it sufficiently established that..."

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: The sentence could be written either way, and both mean the same thing.  But the first sentence is clearer, and the second *may* cause the reader to do a 'double-take' and have to re-read it to understand it properly.  Why substitute a clear sentence by a less-clear one for the sake of 2 words (6 letters)?

Answer (score 1):

Like [TrevorD](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/43980/trevord) said in his comment, I had to do a double-take when reading the second sentence. It *is* technically correct, but could trip some readers up a little.

What you could do is simply cut the first instances of '*that*' from the first version, since it seems to be kind of extraneous. That would leave you with:

> > "...we would argue it is sufficiently established that..."